# nohup not working in following unix following version

Tags: unix, nohup

I have a script `script.sh` and need to give 2 inputs: `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`.

When I run `nohup ./script.sh f1.txt f2.txt &` it gives error like follows

```
./script.sh: print: not found 

./script.sh: print: not found

./script.sh: VPATH=:/: is not an identifier
```

But when I run `./script.sh f1.txt f2.txt` or `./script.sh f1.txt f2.txt &` 
it's working fine.

Not working with `nohup script.sh f1.txt f2.txt`

Unix Version

> Solaris 8 2/02 s28s_u7wos_08a SPARC
>      Copyright 2002 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>      Assembled 18 December 2001

Comment: Do you have something like `#!/bin/bash` as first line of your script ?  It tells system, which shell to use for that script. It is possible, `nohup` uses something different.

Comment: or try `nohup bash ./script.sh`